# Total probability law for quantile functions?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Suppose $X$ is a random variable with distribution function $F_{X}$, and $A$ an event on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Then the law of total probability states
$$P(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(A \mid X=x) d F_{X}(x) .$$
If $X$ admits a density function $f_{X}$, then the result is
$$P(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(A \mid X=x) f_{X}(x) d x. $$
Moreover, for the specific case where $A=\{Y < y \}$, where $y \in \mathbb R$, then this yields
$$P(Y < y )=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(Y <y \mid X=x) f_{X}(x) d x .$$

Is there a total probability law for quantile functions instead of cumulative probability distributions?

For instance, if $Y|X$ is distributed according to $\mathcal N (X,1)$, can we write the quantile function of $Y$ as a functional of the quantile function of $\mathcal N (X,1)$ ?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question very well, however, note that the inverse of $y \mapsto P(Y \leq y)$ is the quantile function and this function does not depend on $X.$

Comment: @WilliamM. The quantile of $Y|X$ depends on $X$ if $Y$ and $X$ are not independent. The question is about the relationship between the quantile of $Y$, the quantile of $X$ and the quantile of $Y|X$. If we were talking about CDFs instead, that relationship would be the total probability law. Is there such a relationship for quantile functions?

Comment: So, the quantile function is also a distribution function but for a different measure (possibly non finite). You will likely need to proceed as in the probabilistic setting using Radon-Nikodym derivatives to write the quantile function in terms of a density of $X.$ However, I doubt that will be probabilistically meaningful!

Comment: @WilliamM. a quantile function is never a distribution function, so I do not know what you are talking about.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_function_(measure_theory)